# Setting default version on Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure

What is the easiest way, without having to create your own utility, to set the default service  version to the latest in Azure Blob Storage ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894041

There is basically nothing to be set in the Azure portal and I am having a difficult time finding working utilities to use for Azure.

For some reason Azure is defaulting to the oldest version which does not send things like the http range header for example.

Any utility that can do this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've updated my Blob Utility tool to support setting the API version, check out https://github.com/Plasma/AzureBlobUtility

I needed to do this as well to support HTTP Range/Resume support.